# Django formsets problem

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to produce a template with many addresses (forms), where you can add, edit and remove them.

Am I doing something wrong with formsets? Here are my views:

```
@login_required
def addresses(request):
    AddressesFormset = modelformset_factory(Address,
                                            can_delete = True,
                                            extra = 0,
                                            exclude = ['user'])

    log.debug('Queryset: %s', request.user.addresses.all())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        log.debug('Formset from POST')
        formset = AddressesFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            log.debug('Saving form')
            formset.save()
            log.debug('Fromset from queryset')
            formset = AddressesFormset(queryset = request.user.addresses.all())
        else:
            log.debug('Form is not valid')
    else:
        log.debug('Fromset from queryset')
        formset = AddressesFormset(queryset = request.user.addresses.all())

    return render_to_response('accounts/addresses.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def add_address(request):
    address = Address.objects.create(user = request.user)
    address.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/addresses/')
```

And template:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    <table class="accountT">
        <tr  class="accountTT">
            <td><p>Ulica, nr domu, mieszkania:</p></td>
            <td>{{ form.street.errors }}{{ form.street }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="accountTT">
            <td><p>Miejscowość:</p></td>
            <td>{{ form.city.errors }}{{ form.city }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="accountTT">
            <td><p>Kod pocztowy:</p></td>
            <td>{{ form.zipcode.errors }}{{ form.zipcode }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="accountTT">
            <td><p>Telefon kontaktowy:</p></td>
            <td>{{ form.phone.errors }}{{ form.phone }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Usuń:</p></td>
            <td>{{ form.DELETE }}</td>
        </tr>
        {{ form.id }}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit:
The problem is that adding a form I have to save the formset (in add_address()). I would like to see how do you treat formsets properly. I don't understand it at all ;).

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't say what your problem is, but you are doing at least one thing wrong.

After confirming that the formset is valid, and then saving it, for some reason you then instantiate *another* formset and fall straight through to the `render_to_response` at the end of the function, so you end up displaying a set of blank forms again.

What you should do at that point is redirect somewhere else, eg to a confirmation page.

Comment: I am not...
Before: formset = AddressesFormset(queryset = request.user.addresses.all())
I do: formset.save().

Without it you can not remove the form :/.

Comment: Yes that's what I said. You save it, then immediately create a new formset. Why?

Comment: Otherwise you can not remove the form from formset... I think something is wrong with my understanding formsets :(.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Why do you think you have to remove a form? Why do you think you have to call `add_addresses` - especially as you don't actually seem to be calling it? What are you actually trying to achieve?